# C++ vs Python precision

Tags: c++, python, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

Trying out a problem of finding the first k digits of a num^num I wrote the same program in C++ and Python

C++

```
long double intpart,num,f_digit,k;
cin>>num>>k;
f_digit= pow(10.0,modf(num*log10(num),&intpart)+k-1);
cout<<f_digit;
```

Python

```
(a,b) = modf(num*log10(num))
f_digits = pow(10,b+k-1)
print f_digits
```

Input

```
19423474 9
```

Output

```
C++    > 163074912
Python > 163074908
```

I checked the results the C++ solution is the accurate one.
Checked it at http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=19423474^19423474

Any idea how can I get the same precision in Python  ???

EDIT : I know about the external library packages to obtain this precision but any NATIVE solution ???

Comment: It's curious that they're different at all, since you would think that they're both using the same basic math library (math.h), the same underlying co-processors, and the same underlying IEEE 754 standard. But perhaps python rewrote its own numeric tower.

Comment: Wolfram alpha says that the last few digits are 2826110976, which is the result of neither your C++ or Python code.

Comment: @sharth: he's listing the *first* few digits, not the *last* few.

Comment: @Will Hartung: they're different because the C code uses `long double`, and Python uses a normal C `double`.

Comment: No one seems to have noticed, but your Python code was subtly wrong; `a` is the fractional component, `b` is the integer component, and the code only makes sense with the fractional component (`a`), but you used `b` in the subsequent `pow` computation (which gets an `OverflowError` thanks to using `float`s, and if fixed to use pure integer math, would take some insane amount of time/memory to produce a result, if it ever finished).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Decimal` is a built in python class that handles floating points correctly (as base 10, not as IEEE 7somethingsomething standard). I don't know if it supports logarithms and all that though.

Edit: It does indeed [support logarithms "and all that".](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#decimal-objects)

You can set the precision of it as well. Default is 28 places, but it can be as large as you want. Think of it as a BigInt for decimals.

Answer (score 2):

Python floats are doubles under the hood, as you discovered.  You will have to resort to C code, or an external library, to get better floating-point precision.

The GMP library is a good one, and it has a python wrapper called 'GMPY', available on [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy/1.11rc1)

Comment: Any of the coding competition don't allow any external API's and i prefer coding in Python for obvious reasons. So i wanted a possible native solution !!!

Answer (score 0):

In general, I would do it this way. However, it doesn't seem to perform anywhere near fast enough for your example numbers.

```
num = 453
k = 9
result = num ** num

print str(result)[:k]
# Prints: '163111849'
```