# The same arithmetic operations give different results in C++ and Python

Tags: python, c++, floating-point

I had to find the result of a function `f(x) = x / (1-x)^2` , where `0 < x < 1`.
The value had to be formatted up to `6` decimal places only.

Here is my C++ code:

```
float x; scanf("%f",&x);
printf("%.6f",x/((1-x)*(1-x)));
```

And I did for the same in Python:

```
 x = float(input()) 
 print ("%.6f" % (x/((1-x)**2)))
```

For some values of x, both the programs give different answers.

For example, for `x = 0.84567`,

C++ gives `35.505867` and Python gives `35.505874`

Why does this happen?
According to solution, the Python answers are right, while C++ answers are wrong.

Comment: there is no right and wrong with floating points, just more or less accurate

Comment: btw if you do care about accuracy then you should use `doule` not `float`

Comment: Welcome to floating point arithmetic. Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846631/c-vs-python-precision

Comment: I guess, python uses cmath under the hood and the difference is in the parsing. C++ give the same result with std::pow(1.f-p, 2.f)

Comment: Using a double [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09510915039f7406) gives the same answer.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: @NathanOliver thank you, I used gcc compiler while you used clang++, I thinks that's why the output is coming different. This seems interesting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    const char data[] = "0.84567";
    float x; 
    sscanf(data, "%f",&x);

    double x2;
    sscanf(data, "%lf",&x2);

    std::cout << std::setprecision(8) << (x/((1-x)*(1-x))) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(8) << (x2/((1-x2)*(1-x2))) << std::endl;
}
```

sample output:

```
35.505867
35.505874
```

Conclusion:

Python is using doubles, you're using floats.

Comment: Yes, this is obvious if you put it the way you have. The differences are too big for it to be anything else. Have an upvote.

Comment: You are both completely incorrect here. They are both using float but with different precisions. Look at the code, both are using float.

Comment: @EamonnKenny: I don't agree. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518653/raising-to-powers-in-c-vs-python/34518772 The `**` forces evaluation in `double` or "higher".

Comment: @EamonnKenny Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6663292/4342498) `float` in python is `double` in C++.

Comment: You are right about the **, but your logic is still wrong. If you use (1-p)*(1-p) you get the same answer. An stackoverflow is not the authority on this, Stroustrup is. There is a difference of precision. And the conclusion above is completely wrong.

Comment: @EamonnKenny since when is Stroustrup an authority on python?

Comment: This problem is language agnostic. Its a numerical analysis issue. The fact that you are seeing it in python is coincidental. Better to remove my posts since nobody appreciates numerical computation anymore.

Comment: @EamonnKenny I think we're all on the same page, barring terminology. Python is written in C. The `float` datatype in python is implemented as a C `double`, which happens to be the same as a c++ `double`. I think we all appreciate that in c++ both `float` and `double` are floating point types of differing precisions.

Comment: What you say now is much clearer. The original statement "python is using doubles, you're using floats" isn't clear enough. If you had have said "Python is using C doubles for its floats, and double double for its double's I would have understood what you meant, but the original statement is ambiguous. Python is using floats for floats, but is its own version of float not C's version of float. Do you see what I'm getting at?

Comment: We are basically saying the same thing, but are communicating it completely different ways.

Answer (score 3):

Python has implemented IEEE 754 double-precision, so its output is closer to real answer.

From documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#representation-error

> Almost all machines today (November 2000) use IEEE-754 floating point
>   arithmetic, and almost all platforms map Python floats to IEEE-754
>   “double precision”.

In C++ float is single-precision. Using `double` instead of `float` should give you similar output.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, floating point numbers in python are implemented using `double` type in C. See [section 5.4](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex) of the Python Documentation.

Running this example on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54f52c9a8b7641fa):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    float pf = 0.84567f;
    printf("%.6f\n",pf/((1-pf)*(1-pf)));

    double pd = 0.84567;
    printf("%.6f\n",pd/((1-pd)*(1-pd)));

    return 0;
}
```

demonstrates the difference:

```
35.505867
35.505874
```